# Struggling with Line Labels in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, flow-charts

I am trying to put a label midway on the vertical line in the arrow looping back in the example below.

My latex reads

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text centered, rounded corners, 
text width=6.5em, minimum height=2em, very thick]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex', thick]
```

And

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    \node [block] (change) {Lane Changes};
    \node [block, below=0.5cm of change] (single) {Single Lane 
    Update};

    \path [line] (change) -- (single);
    \path [line] (single) -- ++(2cm,0)  node [midway] {hi}|-  
    (change);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

I can only manage to get it centered on the bottom horizontal line making up the arrow, how could this be fixed.

[image]

Thanks in advanve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the `node` either after the path specifier, i.e. `|-`, or after the final coordinate of the path, and use `pos=0.25` instead of `midway`. When using `-|`/`|-`, `midway`/`pos=0.5` will always be at the corner of the line, so `pos=0.25` is halfway along the first part of the path.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\tikzset{
  block/.style={rectangle, draw, text centered, rounded corners, 
                text width=6.5em, minimum height=2em, very thick},
  line/.style={draw, -latex', thick}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    \node [block] (change) {Lane Changes};
    \node [block, below=0.5cm of change] (single) {Single Lane 
    Update};

    \path [line] (change) -- (single);
    \path [line] (single) -- ++(2cm,0)  |- node [pos=0.25] {hi}
    (change);
    % or
    %\path [line] (single) -- ++(2cm,0)  |- 
    %(change) node [pos=0.25] {hi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just couldn't make sense of the documentation of tikz, your explanation is very clear.